# EF Core Select RepeatedField

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, grpc

I'm using EF Core and Grpc to serve data.

Now I have to select data to dto model and after AddRange to RepeatedField:

```
var data = context.Users
    .Where(t => t.Id = id)
    .Select(t => new User { Id = t.Id, Name = t.Name, Roles = t.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).ToList() })
    .FirstOrDefault();

...

var response  = new UserResponse { Id = data.Id, Name = data.Name };
response.Roles.AddRange(data.Roles);

return response;
```

Can I somehow select data to Grpc generated class with RepeatedField?

```
var data = context.Users
    .Where(t => t.Id = id)
    .Select(t => new UserResponse { Id = t.Id, Name = t.Name, Roles = /*What to write here?*/ })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `Roles` is read-only, you can write:

```
var data = context.Users
    .Where(t => t.Id = id)
    .Select(t => new UserResponse { Id = t.Id, 
         Name = t.Name, 
         Roles = { t => t.Roles.Select(r => r.Name) }
     })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Behind the scenes, this calls `AddRange` on the `RepeatedField<T>`.

Comment: This is not working with EF Core 7.  It throw `System.ArgumentException: must be reducible node` Guess its related to https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16867 Lets at least put upvoute on this issue(